# Semitones in tremolo harmonica

Tags: harmonica, note-bending, tremolo

I looked all the internet to get this question answered, but it's hopeless. How can I play notes with accidentals – sharp, flats/bemol – in my [24-hole tremolo harmonica](https://uae.souq.com/ae-en/the-24-hole-harmonica-key-of-c-well-suited-for-practice-kq0001-10840997/i/), I want to play [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7_Q10HytB_U&list=PLlTb6OabBi72GRaCHshCgGBLUmSi853yy), How can I play the semitones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this particular harmonica is a simply diatonic one, giving available notes in C major of C D E F G A and B, in various octaves.

To be able to play the 'black keys' - # and b, you really need a *chromatic harmonica*, aka *chromonica*. This has a button on the right, which when pressed, will sharpen any note you play, blow or draw.

It is actually possible, drawing especially, to bend notes downwards. So you could possibly find the notes you need this way.Can't access the dots, so don't know if some of the accidental notes are blown. If so, it's not going to be easy without that chromonica.

Comment: Bending on the blow isn't much harder than bending on the draw, but both are much harder, bordering on impossible, on a tremolo harp. A diatonic blues harp has access to most of the notes of the chromatic scale.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - but, I forgot to say, keeping those bent notes in good tune/pitch isn't easy, on any harp.  Incidentally, congrats on attaining 3rd position in the votes cast table. Slim had retained it for a very long time.